# How can I set up multiple tabs/RSS feeds in Blogger?

Tags: rss, blogger

Is it possible to set up multiple tabs on Blogger?

For instance, if I had `animal.blogspot.com` - how would I be able to set up separate "Dog" and "Cat" tabs, each with their own RSS feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set up multiple feeds for the same blog based on label categories, use this format as [explained here](http://labnol.blogspot.in/2007/08/offer-rss-feeds-for-blogger-search.html) -

http://{yourblogname}.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/{label}

This trick still works for the reincarnated form of Feedburner.

Answer (score 0):

For the tabs part:

Add a Pages gadget, and put it just underneath your header in the section where you'd expect to see a tab-bar.   Make each entry point to a "web page" with an url like:

```
http://www.yourBlogURL.xxx/search/label/yourLabelName
```

For the feeds, they already exist, as per the answer mvark

Answer (score -1):

For the RSS part:

Yahoo Pipes, filter by item.category.

Expanding: [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) allows you to create custom RSS. For this question, you simply put your blog RSS as source. Then you add a filter that allows only items of one category (something like this: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=6b44f0135bde67b74a8561ba4a06747c). Use the output as the RSS for that category. Repeat as necesary. Hope is more clear now.

Comment: Please expand your answer; the way it is now, it’s not very helpful.

Comment: Now its expanded :P

Comment: while I agree that your answer is better now that it's expanded, it doesn't cover the full question.